# 'not enough arguments for format string' when attempting to insert data into MySQL DB using sqlalchemy or mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert data into a MySQL DB and have hit a wall whereby I am getting a 'not enough arguments for format string' error even though everything looks completely fine. Here's my code:

```
for index,row in player_df.iterrows():
    query = "INSERT INTO players (id,starter,jersey_number,nickname,position,usual_first_name,teamid) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=%s,starter=%s,jersey_number=%s,nickname=%s,position=%s,usual_first_name=%s,teamid=%s"
    values = (row['id'],row['starter'],row['jersey_number'],row['nickname'],row['position'],row['usual_first_name'],row['teamid'])
    sql_engine.execute(query, values)
```

Did I overlook something or neglect a parameter? Thanks. I've spent all day on this and it's quite critical for me to resolve. When I do a print statement it all looks fine and I see the expected number of variables: 
('975385', 'True', '31', 'Coronel', 'Goalkeeper', 'Carlos Miguel', '32658')
7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `values(col_name)` in the UPDATE clause to refer to the values that would have been inserted in order to avoid having to pass the same arguments twice:

```
for index,row in player_df.iterrows():
    query = """INSERT INTO players (id,starter,jersey_number,nickname,position,usual_first_name,teamid) 
               VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY
               UPDATE id=values(id)
                    , starter=values(starter)
                    , jersey_number=values(jersey_number)
                    , nickname=values(nickname)
                    , position=values(position)
                    , usual_first_name=values(usual_first_name)
                    , teamid=values(teamid)"""
    values = (row['id'],row['starter'],row['jersey_number'],row['nickname'],row['position'],row['usual_first_name'],row['teamid'])
    sql_engine.execute(query, values)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ilja! I wasn't aware of the values(col_name) feature and didn't pick up on the fact that I needed to pass the arguments twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs 14 Values 7 for the inserrt and 7 more for the oN DUPLICATE
So you must doif the UPDATE Values are the same as the insert.

```
for index,row in player_df.iterrows():
    query = "INSERT INTO players (id,starter,jersey_number,nickname,position,usual_first_name,teamid) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=%s,starter=%s,jersey_number=%s,nickname=%s,position=%s,usual_first_name=%s,teamid=%s"
    values = (row['id'],row['starter'],row['jersey_number'],row['nickname'],row['position'],row['usual_first_name'],row['teamid'],row['id'],row['starter'],row['jersey_number'],row['nickname'],row['position'],row['usual_first_name'],row['teamid'])
    sql_engine.execute(query, values)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @nbk. I should have noticed that I didn't pass values twice.